# Type checking in hierarchy: getParentOfType()

Tags: typescript, types, typechecking

I'm still having a hard time with the type checking system of TypeScript. Suppose a composite that holds a collection of elements which all derive from a common base class. How can I implement a function that recursively goes up the hierarchy and returns the first anchestor of a given type?

```
abstract class Employee
{
    public Superior: Employee;

    /** THIS IS NOT WORKING */
    public getSuperiorOfType<T extends Employee>( type: typeof T ): T
    {
        if (this instanceof T) return this;
        else if (this.Superior !== undefined) return this.getSuperiorOfType(type);
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {}
class TeamLead extends Employee {}
class Developer extends Employee {}

let tom = new Manager();
let suzanne = new TeamLead();
let ben = new Developer();

ben.Superior = suzanne;
suzanne.Superior = tom;

let x = ben.getSuperiorOfType( Manager ); // x = tom
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The type of 'class type' can not be declared as `typeof T`. `typeof` in type position is applicable only to variables, not types. You need to use so-called [constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) for that:

   ```
   public getSuperiorOfType<T extends Employee>(type: { new(...args: any[]): T}): T
   ```
2. You can't check if an object is `instanceof` of a generic type parameter - `instanceof T` does not work because generic type parameters do not exist at runtime. But you have `type` as actual function parameter, so  `instanceof type` should work.
3. There is no real recursion in your code - you are always calling `getSuperiorOfType` for the same `this` object. You need to call it as `this.Superior.getSuperiorOfType(...)` to move up one step in hierarchy.

   ```
   abstract class Employee
   {
       public Superior: Employee;

       public getSuperiorOfType<T extends Employee>(type: { new(...args: any[]): T}): T
       {
           if (this instanceof type) return this;
           else if (this.Superior !== undefined) return this.Superior.getSuperiorOfType(type);
       }
   }

   class Manager extends Employee {}
   class TeamLead extends Employee {}
   class Developer extends Employee {}

   let tom = new Manager();
   let suzanne = new TeamLead();
   let ben = new Developer();

   ben.Superior = suzanne;
   suzanne.Superior = tom;


   let x = ben.getSuperiorOfType(Manager); 
   console.log(x === tom); // true
   ```